# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have execute Stored Procedure from Spring data JPA for that I am using `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`, but getting exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery;
```

But in EntityManger interface I can see this method is declared as

```
public abstract StoredProcedureQuery createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(String 
paramString);"
```

Please help to resolve this issue. Below is the code

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="get_buyer_details", procedureName="GETBUYERACCTSDTL", resultClasses= BuyerDetailsOut.class,
        parameters= {@StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="buyerId", type=String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="cardNo", type=String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="prodType", type=String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name="buyerDetailsOut", type=void.class)}

)
public class BuyerDetails {


@Id
private long id;


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Repository::

```
@Repository
public interface AccountDao extends JpaRepository<BuyerDetails, Long> {

static final String AA = "get_buyer_details";
@Procedure(name=AA)
public List<BuyerDetailsOut> getBuyerDetails(@Param("buyerId") String buyerId, @Param("cardNo") String cardNo, @Param("prodType") String prodType);

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <!--Jackson databind excluded since internally used version quarantined by IQ Nexus (CDCR-6935)-->
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.ojdbc.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you confirm by mvn dependency:tree and mvn dependency:analyze that there is no conflict in you dependecies?

Comment: Thanks @MohammadRezaAlagheband, there was conflicts in Hibernate-JPA jar, somehow two jars with different version were added. Now that issue resolved and I am getting another exception " java.sql.SQLException: The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters".  This exception is occurring when I use  OUT or REF_CURSOR. If stored procedure has only IN param then works fine. Please suggest how to use this with OUT/REF_CURSOR. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please change name in `NamedStoredProcedureQuery` like below and also change procedure name in repository like defined stored procedure name.

```
 @Entity
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="createNamedStoredProcedureQuery", procedureName="GETBUYERACCTSDTL", resultClasses= BuyerDetailsOut.class,
            parameters= {@StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="buyerId", type=String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="cardNo", type=String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="prodType", type=String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name="buyerDetailsOut", type=void.class)}

    )
```

and make change in repository too call by procedure name.

```
@Repository
public interface AccountDao extends JpaRepository<BuyerDetails, Long> {

    static final String AA = "GETBUYERACCTSDTL";
    @Procedure(name=AA)
    public List<BuyerDetailsOut> getBuyerDetails(@Param("buyerId") String buyerId, @Param("cardNo") String cardNo, @Param("prodType") String prodType);

}
```